# Error while running ComBat for microarray data

Tags: r

I am actually am a molecular biologist and have very little or no idea on coding. I was just following online instructions to run ComBat to normalize batch effects in my microarray samples which I had run in 4 different batches over 3 years where I believe there will be batch effects.
I got as far as preparing the sample expression and information files and running it in R. But at a point I get the following error:

```
ComBat('Expressiondata.txt','Information.txt')
Reading Sample Information File
Reading Expression Data File
Found 4 batches
Found 1 covariate(s)
Standardizing Data across genes
Fitting L/S model and finding priors
Finding parametric adjustments
Adjusting the Data
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 47314
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you're using the `sva` package? Difficult to help without knowing what your expression data and batch data files look like. The error indicates some kind of mismatch between the two. Perhaps you also need a model matrix?

Comment: I was following the instructions and script i got from the following website:  http://www.bu.edu/jlab/wp-assets/ComBat/Usage.html   . They do not mention the need for a model matrix.

Comment: Also what would the 0 stand for in 0, 47314?  Because I do have 47314 rows and 18 columns.

Comment: That script is very old; I'd be surprised if it still works. The ComBat method is now implemented in the Bioconductor `sva` package: https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/sva.html.

Comment: Thank You. The examples and script provided use preexisting data. I would like to know how I could use my tab delimited txt file to proceed and build the model matrices. Are there any references with guidelines?

Comment: Basically, study the format of the example data, figure out how to make yours look the same.